# Performance issue with vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am using a couple of structs in my code. The first struct is constructed after reading data from a line of text file and the second struct contains a vector of structs of the first kind.

```
 struct A{
       long a, b, c, d, e, f;
       string x, y, z;
 }

 struct B{
       string id1;
       vector<A> aVec;
 }
```

Now I read my file and initialize a vector of struct B's. Then based on what the incoming new line's id1 and id2 are, I create a new A and push it into the correct B.

```
 vector<B> bVec;
 vector<A> atmpVec;
 B btmp;
 //Initializing bVec
 for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
 {
     btmp.id1 = "c"+to_string(i);
     btmp.aVec = atmpVec;
     //tried using reserve too.
     //btmp.aVec.reserve(50000);

     bVec.push_back(btmp);
 }
 //readerCode
 while(getline(file, line))
 {
      A = readA(line); //readA reads and sets the fields of struct A.
      int idx = getBIdx(bVec, A); //getBIdx returns which B struct should i be using.
      bVec[idx].aVec.push_back(A);
 }
```

Now the last line has become a bottleneck. If I simply declare a vector of A and keep on pushing back to it, the time taken to process a million records is ~10 seconds.
On the other hand, with this approach, it takes 60 seconds to just process 50k records.
Is there a way I can keep the above general structure without losing the performance.
Any ways to efficiently implement this?

Comment: That code doesn't compile. `A = readA(line)` isn't a valid statement, and you're missing semicolons.

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11? Because this code would really benefit from move semantics.

Comment: I am using c++0x, isn't that the same as c++11?

Comment: @Naveen: no, C++11 is a huge upgrade of previous versions of C++.

Comment: @NaveenSharma Yes, they refer to the same standard. C++0x comes from the expectation that the standard would be published before 2010.

Comment: Don't use temporaries and then `push_back`. Either add a constructor and construct the object in-place using `vector::emplace_back` or `push_back` a default initialized version and modify it using `vector::back`. `vector::reserve` on `bVec`.

Comment: have upgraded to g++4.7 and have c++11 support.

Comment: Could you provide the real code so we could benchmark ourselves? Currently there is a bunch of stuff that doesn't exactly make sense (the assignment of `btmp.avec = atmpvec` while `atmpvec` hasn't been used etc.

Comment: well, this was weird, installed g++4.7, compiled using -c++11 and the code slowed down by furthers 20 seconds. what was taking 55 secs earlier now takes 75.

Comment: @NaveenSharma: Did you enable compiler optimisations with `-O3`?

Comment: @pmr `pushback(std::move(A))` shouldn't be much slower than those alternatives.

Comment: @nosid,have used both -O3 and -Ofast.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Really? The `long` members wont be optimized to a `memcpy` and `string` is just notoriously evil when copies are involved. That sounds expensive to me (in relationship to what the rest of the code does).

Comment: @pmr, if possible can you point to some literature about this move in c++11? I'd like to explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the time spent in the getBIdx method ? Pushing to a single vector or one between N should be almost the same.

Trying with a simple getBIdx:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

const int NUMBER_OF_A = 3E7;
const int NUMBER_OF_B = 7;

struct A {
  long a, b, c, d, e, f;
  string x, y, z;
};

struct B {
  string id1;
  vector<A> aVec;
};

struct A readA() {
  A a;
  a.a = 1;
  a.b = 2;
  return a;
}

int getBIdx(const A& a) {
  return rand() % NUMBER_OF_B;
}

void Test1() {
  vector<B> bVec;
  for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_B; i++) {
    B btmp;
    bVec.push_back(btmp);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_A; ++i) {
    A a = readA();
    int idx = getBIdx(a);
    bVec[idx].aVec.push_back(a);
  }
}

void Test2() {
  vector<A> vector;

  for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_A; ++i) {
    A a = readA();
    int idx = getBIdx(a);
    vector.push_back(a);
  }
}

int main() {
  time_t start = time(0);
  Test1();
  time_t end_of_test1 = time(0);
  Test2();
  time_t end_of_test2 = time(0);

  cout << "Elapsed test 1:" << end_of_test1 - start << " s" << endl;
  cout << "Elapsed test 2:" << end_of_test2 - end_of_test1 << " s" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Result: (old Pentium 4 single core machine)

```
Elapsed test 1:17 s
Elapsed test 2:13 s
```

So it's slower but not that slower.

With -O3 the difference is even smaller:

```
Elapsed test 1:9 s
Elapsed test 2:7 s
```

Comment: That was my first suspicion but have verified that is not the case.

Comment: I tried adding a.x = "AB"; and a.y = "xxxxxYYYYY"; to your readA and it fails to run completely.

Comment: What do you mean by fails to run completely ? By adding strings you consume more RAM, so if you don't have a crazy amount of RAM it's a good idea to decrease NUMBER_OF_A as you increase the size of the record you put in the vector. With a.x = "AB"; and a.y = "xxxxxYYYYY"; but NUMBER_OF_A = 5E6; it takes 6 and 7 seconds (-O3).

Comment: you were right! it was the idx function coz I was passing bVec to it by value. Running your code made me curios and eventually solved the issue.

Comment: @NaveenSharma Ok, please remember this for any future question you may ask: post complete examples. There is a reason for this, the issue here was in code you didn't post...

Answer (score 0):

I　would try to optimize this code in two ways

1. define `vector<A*> aVec` instead of `vector<A> aVec`, to avoid copy constructor call ,since you are using C++0x
2. estimate the size of size of aVec in B, using resize() to resever some space might save some time

Answer (score 0):

You should probably using the sizing constructor on bVec as it's size is known.
Then for the main culprit of filling it with vector of A, you probably 
want to use vector::reserve on each avec inside bVec with an arbitrary size depending on your number of data to be fed.

Also, are you sure you compile with -O3 ?

Comment: I compiled with -Ofast

Comment: Tried reserve, no improvement. I will edit code to refelct how I did it.